# TcpClient disconnects after sending

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

My TcpClient keeps disconnecting after writing a byte-array in Visual Basic .NET

[image]

Here's my method of sending a byte-array:

```
        Dim Data As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hey man!")

        Using Ns As NetworkStream = Client.GetStream
                Ns.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
        End Using
```

Oh, and I should mention that the disconnect is invoked because of a Try-Catch statement on the sending sub. But something isn't right about the sending method.

Comment: Where and how do you create the TCPClient object? It may go out of scope and be disposed of automatically thus disconnecting you.

Comment: Sorry, I added in the bottom of my post that the disconnection is caused by a Try-Catch statement. Basically, if it fails sending it'll take it as if the Client/Server lost connection between eachother. If I connect to the server without trying to send anything it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear on whether this is the listener closing the port or the client breaking the communication, but with that aside, let me ask if your listener has a keepalive property you can set to TRUE?

Comment: Is the server trying to send a response back?  Are you trying to read a response?  The code you posted works fine.

Comment: Ill take a peek at this shortly.